# add material Date/Time Picker library to android studio manualy

Tags: android, android-studio

i want to manually add this library [material Date/Time Picker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/).
 to my project.with out this code.

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0'
}
```

please help me

Comment: why would you want that

Comment: Because In our country we need vpn to compile ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to this [link](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/tree/master/library/src/main) - (same library).
2. Copy java codes to your own custom packages in your project.
3. Copy the items from all resource files also.
4. Resolve all import errors manually.
5. Its done.